# Put a new tr row between highest and lowest values based on its number using jq/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table in html built with json (there are columns that describe what the numbers are also):

```
1
2
7
10
11
15
```

Now from a button i want is when user enters a new row, I want the number to go in its place. E.g. if 4, it should be between 2 and 7. If 14, it should be between 11 and 15.

```
$('tbody#days > tr:nth-child(' + daynumber-1 + ')').after(new_row_data);
```

failed to work because the index couldn't be found. It works sometimes if for e.g. I have 3 and 5 and tried to insert 4.

I thought have looping the column top to bottom but i usually have 100-113 rows and I am wondering if there is a practical and efficient way of doing this.

Any tips?

Comment: are the rows always going to be in sorted order?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you posted should work fine. However, this will throw an error if the all days are greater than the input.

For efficiency, you could maintain an array of already inserted days and populate it as more days are being inserted.

Before each insertion, look through the array of days and find a spot for that day and just insert it right away. Code for that will be

```
$('tbody#days > tr').eq( lowerIndex ).after( new_row_data );
```